# Flutter web not loading images

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, assets, dart-html

Hi I wanted to upload my website today but I realized that I can't use images as `AssetImage`. After looking for a solution I found a possible way where I use `NetworkImage` with the url
`yoururl/assets/assets/image.jpg` for example.

Now this isn't working for me as well. I tried running it with the command `flutter run -d -chrome --webkit-renderer html` but this didn't work as well.

What other possibilities would work here? is there maybe some site where I could upload my images?

Comment: Could you provide more detail information? Probably, some error message

Answer (score 0):

When using asset images on the web, remove the assets at the beginning of the asset path.

Sample ;

**Normal state** : "assets/images/someImage.png",

**Web** : "/images/someImage.png"